# How to refresh sys.path?

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, reload, sys.path

I've installed some packages during the execution of my script as a user. Those packages were the first user packages, so python didn't add `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to the `sys.path` before script run. I want to import those installed packages. But I cannot because they are not in `sys.path`.

How can I refresh `sys.path`?

I'm using python 2.7.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As explained in [What sets up sys.path with Python, and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271494/what-sets-up-sys-path-with-python-and-when) `sys.path` is populated with the help of builtin `site.py` module.

So you just need to reload it. You cannot it in one step because you don't have `site` in your namespace. To sum up:

```
import site
from importlib import reload
reload(site)
```

That's it.

Comment: This will solve most of the problems. If you deleted or renamed a file, pay attention to remove the old bytecode, otherwise, it will be used by Python. 
And if you are using Python 3 (I know the question is about 2.7 but I ended up here searching for a solution for 3), then remember to use importlib.invalidate_caches() or the old content of the file system may be used.

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to add it directly to your `sys.path` with:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/your/new/path")
```

Or, if it needs to be found first:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, "/your/new/path")
```